# AuthenticationForm not working

Tags: python, django

I'm experimenting with Django and I tried to create a login/register application. Here's where I've stuck - I'm able to register users, but then I can't login with them. Here's the code I think is relevant:

**views.py**

```
def login(request, template='accounts/sign_in.html'):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(reverse('games'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST.copy()
        if 'password' in post:
            post['password'] = make_password(post['password'])
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=post)

        if form.is_valid():
            login(request, form.get_user())
            messages.success(
                request, "Successfully logged in.", extra_tags='success')
            return redirect(reverse('games'))
        else:
            messages.warning(
                request, "Wrong username or password." + request.POST['username'] + " " + request.POST['password'], extra_tags='error')
            return redirect(reverse('login'))
    return views.login(request, template)

def register(request, template='accounts/sign_up.html'):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(reverse('home'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = User(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                password=make_password(form.cleaned_data['password1']),
                is_active=True,
            )
            new_user.save()

            messages.success(request, "Your account was successfully created.")
            return redirect(reverse('games'))
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    return render(request, template, {'register_form': form})
```

When I try to log in with a user I've created (username: qwe, password: qweqweqwe), I get redjrected to login again, but the exact same username and password are printed in the message:

```
Wrong username or password.qwe qweqweqwe
```

However, when I try the interactive shell, here's what I get:

```
>>> User.objects.all()
[<User: admin>, <User: asd>, <User: qwe>]
>>> User.objects.all()[2]
<User: qwe>
>>> User.objects.all()[2].password
u'pbkdf2_sha256$10000$HM2k6uDntJ68$DLqHKcGxtJG7pJC7tbZcm29vB88LEgaw2xroqZEkTFw='
```

So I have such a user and it's a valid account.

Comment: what does make_password do? What error do you get from .is_valid() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue no. 1 - wrong `login()`

This is probably the problem:

```
login(request, form.get_user())
```

You already have a `login` function and it happens to be a view. I suppose you want to confirm user authentication (`form.is_valid()` does not do that automatically).

More details are in [the documentation of `auth` module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in):

> ### How to log a user in
>
> If you have an authenticated user you want to attach to the current
>   session - this is done with a `login()` function.
>
> ## login()
>
> To log a user in, from a view, use `login()`. It takes an HttpRequest
>   object and a User object. `login()` saves the user’s ID in the session,
>   using Django’s session framework.
>
> Note that any data set during the anonymous session is retained in the
>   session after a user logs in.
>
> This example shows how you might use both `authenticate()` and `login()`:
>
> ```
> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
>
> def my_view(request):
>     username = request.POST['username']
>     password = request.POST['password']
>     user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
>     if user is not None:
>         if user.is_active:
>             login(request, user)
>             # Redirect to a success page.
>         else:
>             # Return a 'disabled account' error message
>     else:
>         # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
> ```

### Issue no. 2 - wrong password

As Paulo mentioned, `AuthenticationForm` already handles password hashing. Please read the official documentation for examples:

[Using the Django authentication system: Authentication in Web requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you don't need to call `make_password` in this one:

```
if 'password' in post:
    post['password'] = make_password(post['password'])
form = AuthenticationForm(data=post)
```

Just pass the normal `request.POST` to `data` and the form itself do the encryption and test it against the database. This is the fragment of `AuthenticationForm`'s `clean` method where it do this:

```
def clean(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

    if username and password:
        self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username,
                                       password=password)
    ...
```

You can see the whole definition [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py).

I suppose your using official `make_password` function from `django.contrib,auth` but take a look at the docs closely, normally, user register functions do this automatically so you won't have to do it.

Anyways:

Check the errors form is yielding after `is_valid` call and change your `login` code to this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
```

Hope this helps!